# How to only fire event if flipswitch is manually switched

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, event-handling, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

I've created an jQuery Mobile flipswitch like this

```
<select id="flip" data-role="flipswitch">
    <option value="animal">Lion</option>
    <option value="flower">Rose</option>
</select>
```

and I listen to changes on this flipswitch

```
$( document ).on( 'change', '#flip', function( e ) {
   console.log( 'changed' );
}
```

But I don't want the event to be triggered if I change the value of the flipswitch by

```
$( '#flip' ).val( 'flower' ).flipswitch( 'refresh' );
```

How do I check if a flipswitch has changed by interacting with it directly or setting a value and refreshing the flipswitch?

I've created an example of the unwanted behavior under [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7WJLM/1/).

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ZPTPL/

Comment: that will work thank you for your quick answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `.on()` to attach `change` event and `.off()` to remove it - before you bind it again - whenever you change the value dynamically.

Wrap all your code in `pagecreate` event, it is equvilant to `.ready()`.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#main", function () {

    /* change event handler */
    function flipChanged(e) {
        var id = this.id,
            value = this.value;
        console.log(id + " has been changed! " + value);
    }

    /* add listener - this will be removed once other buttons are clicked */
    $("#flip").on("change", flipChanged);

    $('#setlion').on('vclick', function (e) {
        $("#flip")
            .off("change") /* remove previous listener */
            .val('animal') /* update value */
            .flipswitch('refresh') /* re-enhance switch */
            .on("change", flipChanged); /* add listener again */
    });

    $('#setrose').on('vclick', function (e) {
        $("#flip")
            .off("change")
            .val('flower')
            .flipswitch('refresh')
            .on("change", flipChanged);
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ZPTPL/)**